# How do I manually select an initial storyboard without the plist from the App Delegate?

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard

I need to be able to select a storyboard with its initial UIViewController upon application launch per boolean choice.  Each storyboard works... per .plist (original) setup.

So I removed the default initial storyboard entry in the app's plist; and attempted to do it manually.

What I got is a black screen on my device.

The variables 'storyboard', 'controller', 'window' are all non-nil.  Yet I get no screen.   Why?

Here's the code:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIColor *blissRed = [UIColor colorWithRed:228.0/255.0 green:0.0 blue:27.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.tintColor = blissRed;

    BOOL introStoryboard = YES;  // ...artificial condition for discussion.

    UIStoryboard *storyboard;
    UIViewController *controller;

    if (introStoryboard) {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Intro" bundle:nil];
        controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kIntroStoryboardBeginning];
    } else {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Bliss" bundle:nil];
        controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kBlissStoryboardBeginning];
    }

    [self.window setRootViewController:controller];

    return YES;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just forgot the following line before return

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in the situation once. I resolved it by doing-

```
[navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

So what u need to do is -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIColor *blissRed = [UIColor colorWithRed:228.0/255.0 green:0.0 blue:27.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.tintColor = blissRed;

    BOOL introStoryboard = YES;  // ...artificial condition for discussion.

    UIStoryboard *storyboard;
    UIViewController *controller;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    if (introStoryboard) {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Intro" bundle:nil];
        controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kIntroStoryboardBeginning];
} else {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Bliss" bundle:nil];
        controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kBlissStoryboardBeginning];
}

   [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

return YES;
```

}